# RGBDSLAM on ROS Hydro: Missing resources

Tags: catkin, ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone!

So, I have been trying to install RGBDSLAM on Hydro for quite some time now, but just can't get it to work. I was finally able to install Hydro from source successfully in `/opt/ros/hydro` and then I setup a catkin workspace in `~/ros/`.

However, when I try to install the RGBDSLAM package I downloaded into`~/ros/src`, I get the following error:

```
ERROR: the following packages/stacks could not have their rosdep keys resolved to system dependencies: 
rgbdslam: Missing resource roslang 
ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/hydro/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/ros 
ROS path [1]=/opt/ros/hydro/share 
ROS path [2]=/opt/ros/hydro/stacks 
ROS path [3]=/home/pb1/ros/src
```

I can `roscd` into the RGBDSLAM directory just fine, but whenever I try to install it comes up with these errors. I suspect this all has to do with how my catkin overlay / ROS directory is configured, but I could be wrong.

If anyone can help me through this, I'll really appreciate it.

Thanks!

P.S. I am working with Ubuntu ARM on a Pandaboard, if that is any help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/130111/rgbdslam-on-ros-hydro:-missing-resources/) by [AndrewLawson](https://answers.ros.org/users/11631/andrewlawson/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2014-02-17

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I guess the rgbdslam_freiburg package is not build with "catkin" but "rosbuild", try to pull the package to a new workplace(without catkin) and add the workplace path to the ROS_PACKAGE_PATH.  remember to follow the wiki  http://wiki.ros.org/rgbdslam

---

Originally posted by [lguodongustc](https://answers.ros.org/users/10416/lguodongustc/) with karma: 61 on 2014-03-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0